# Mean and covariance matrix for posterior distribution with linear model with known $y$ and unknown $x$

Tags: bayesian, linear-model, latent-variable

Let $\mathcal{X} := \left \{\boldsymbol{x_i} \right \}_{i=1}^N$ denote inputs and $\mathcal{Y} := \left \{y_i \right \}_{i=1}^N$ denote outputs. Let $\boldsymbol{X} := \left [\boldsymbol{x}_1, \dots, \boldsymbol{x}_N \right ]^T $ where each vector $\boldsymbol{x}_i$ has a $1$ as the first element of the vector and $\boldsymbol{y} := \left [y_1, \dots, y_n \right ]^T$, where $\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\theta}$.

Then consider the following generative model with

- Likelihood: $p(\mathcal{Y} \mid \mathcal{X}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{y} \mid \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_\eta)$ and
- Prior: $p(\mathcal{X}) = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{X} \mid \boldsymbol{\mu}_0, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0)$.

We have a linear model but assume that $\boldsymbol{y}$ is observed but $\boldsymbol{X}$ is not. Assume that $\boldsymbol{\theta}$, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_\eta$, $\boldsymbol{\mu}_0$, and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0$ are known. Assume $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_\eta$ is spherical.

I would like to obtain the mean and covariance matrix for the posterior distribution $p(\mathcal{X} \mid \mathcal{Y}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{X} \mid \boldsymbol{\mu}_N, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_N)$.

As can be seen below, I attempted to derive the posterior mean and covariance matrix using the formulas for the multivariate Gaussian log-likelihood plus log-prior and then factorizing but was unable to simplify any further. I know that one possible strategy in a typical linear regression setting (which this problem is not) is to use completing the square to match the form of the mean and covariance matrix of the posterior. I attempted something similar in my case but could not find a way to collect the terms to match them.

Any hints about how to proceed would be appreciated. I believe there is some matrix identity I can use. Xi'an mentioned one in their comment but I am not certain about how to apply it.

---

### Attempt at univariate derivation

Following Xi'an's advice, I am attempting the univariate derivation first to see if that will give insight into the multivariate derivation where I am far less familiar with matrix identities.

We start with

$$
\log \left [ p(y \mid x)p(x) \right ] = \log \mathcal{N}(y \mid \beta_0 + \beta_1 x, \sigma^2_\eta) + \log \mathcal{N}(x \mid \mu_0, \sigma^2_0)
$$

Expanding the formula for the univariate Gaussian and removing some constants:

$$
-\frac{1}{2} \left (\log \sigma^2_\eta + \frac{(y - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x)^2}{\sigma^2_\eta} - \log \sigma^2_0 + \frac{(x - \mu_0)^2}{\sigma^2_0} \right ) + const.
$$

Then factorizing and grouping quadratic and linear terms:

$$
\begin{align}
    &= -\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{-2 \beta_1 xy + 2\beta_0\beta_1 x + \beta_1^2x^2}{\sigma^2_\eta} + \frac{x^2 - 2 \mu_0 x}{\sigma^2_0} \right ) + const. \\
    & = -\frac{1}{2} \left ( \underbrace{\beta_1^2x^2\sigma^{-2}_\eta + x^2\sigma^{-2}_0}_{\text{quadratic}} -\underbrace{2\beta_1xy\sigma^{-2}_\eta - 2\mu_0x\sigma^{-2}_0 + 2\beta_0\beta_1x\sigma^{-2}_\eta}_{\text{linear}} \right ) + const. \\
    &= -\frac{1}{2} \left ( x^2 (\beta_1^2\sigma^{-2}_\eta + \sigma^{-2}_0) - 2x (\beta_1y\sigma^{-2}_\eta + \mu_0\sigma^{-2}_0 - \beta_0\beta_1\sigma^{-2}_\eta) \right ) + const.
\end{align}
$$

Now we look at the log posterior which should be proportional to what we've just derived. Grouping the quadratic and linear terms in the same way:

$$
\begin{align}
    \log p(x \mid y, \theta) &= \mathcal{N}(x \mid \mu_N, \sigma_N) \\
    &= -\frac{1}{2} \left ( x^2(\sigma^{-2}_N) - 2x (\mu_N \sigma^{-2}_N) + \mu^2_N\sigma^{-2}_N \right ) + const.
\end{align}
$$

Now matching the posterior variance we get

$$
\begin{align}
    \sigma^{-2}_N &= \beta_1^2\sigma^{-2}_\eta + \sigma^{-2}_0 \\
    \sigma^{2}_N &= (\beta_1^2\sigma^{-2}_\eta + \sigma^{-2}_0)^{-1} \\
    &= \left (\frac{\beta_1^2}{\sigma^2_\eta} + \frac{1}{\sigma^{2}_0} \right )^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$

And finally, the posterior mean

$$
\begin{align}
    \mu_N \sigma^{-2}_N &= \beta_1y\sigma^{-2}_\eta + \mu_0\sigma^{-2}_0 - \beta_0\beta_1\sigma^{-2}_\eta \\
    \mu_N &= \sigma^2_N \left (\frac{\beta_1y}{\sigma^2_\eta} - \frac{\beta_0\beta_1}{\sigma^2_\eta} + \frac{\mu_0}{\sigma^2_0} \right ) 
\end{align}
$$

A quick check with a sample $x$ and $y$ shows that this formula is correct.

---

### Attempt at multivariate derivation

For the multivariate derivation I begin with

$$
\log \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{y} \mid \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\theta}, \sigma^2_\eta \boldsymbol{I}) + \log \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{X} \mid \boldsymbol{\mu_0}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0).
$$

Then expand, collecting constants (including terms independent of $\boldsymbol{X}$) to obtain

$$
= -\frac{1}{2} \left (\sigma^{-2}_\eta(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\theta})^T (\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\theta}) + (\boldsymbol{X} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_0)^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{-1} (\boldsymbol{X} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_0 ) \right ) + const.
$$

Factor to obtain

$$
= -\frac{1}{2} \left (\sigma^{-2}_\eta\boldsymbol{y}^T \boldsymbol{y} - 2 \sigma^{-2}_\eta \boldsymbol{y}^T \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\theta} + \boldsymbol{\theta}^T \sigma^{-2}_\eta \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\theta} + \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_0 \boldsymbol{X} - 2 \boldsymbol{\mu}_0^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_0 \boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{\mu}_0^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_0 \boldsymbol{\mu}_0 \right ) + const.
$$

From here I believe I can ignore terms one and six because they do not depend on $\boldsymbol{X}$. Doing so and rearranging we can see that

$$
= -\frac{1}{2} \left (\underbrace{\boldsymbol{\theta}^T \sigma^{-2} \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\theta} + \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_x \boldsymbol{X} }_{\text{quadratic}} - \underbrace{2 \sigma^{-2} \boldsymbol{y}^T \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\theta} + - 2 \boldsymbol{\mu}_x^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_x \boldsymbol{X}}_{\text{linear}} \right ) + const.
$$

As with the univariate approach, we can then take a look at the posterior distribution and get it into the same form. Since the posterior is proportional to the joint distribution $p(\boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{y})$, we should be able to obtain the posterior mean and covariance matrix in the same way.

The posterior has the form

$$
p(\boldsymbol{X} \mid \boldsymbol{y}, \boldsymbol{\theta}) = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{X}; \boldsymbol{\mu}_N, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_N).
$$

Factorizing produces

$$
\begin{align}
    &-\frac{1}{2} (\boldsymbol{X} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_N)^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_N^{-1} (\boldsymbol{X} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_N ) + const. \\
    &=-\frac{1}{2} \left (\boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_N \boldsymbol{X} - 2 \boldsymbol{\mu}_N^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_N \boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{\mu}_N^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_N \boldsymbol{\mu}_N \right ) + const.,
\end{align}
$$

where there is a quadratic, linear, and constant term respectively. Matching the quadratic and linear terms with the likelihood/prior factorization above, we can see how the matrix multiplication must look to proceed in this way.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to proceed from here or even if I should use the same approach in the multivariate case as I did in the univariate one. Any hints on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: @Xi'an I added an edit to explain what $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are though I am not sure if it was necessary. Can you explain why this is not an inference problem? Do you mean that it's not an inference problem since I am not trying to infer model parameters, i.e. $p(\theta \mid X, y)$? Can you give a hint about what direction to go in next to derive the conditional distribution?

Comment: I added some of my work in attempt to try to get to the posterior mean and covariance matrix but I am not entirely show how to proceed from here or if my approach is even correct.

Comment: I would consider the problem where you have only _one_ observed $\mathcal Y\in\mathbb R$ and _one_ corresponding unobserved $\mathcal X\in\mathbb R$ more realistic (and avoiding Normal distributions over matrices).

Comment: Otherwise, use a [matrix Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution), which means representing terms like$$\boldsymbol{\theta}^T \sigma^{-2}_\eta \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\theta}$$as$$\sigma^{-2}_\eta \sigma^{-2}_\eta \text{tr}\{\boldsymbol{\theta}\boldsymbol{\theta}^T \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{X} \}$$

Comment: I think I finally understand the issue and what you are trying to say. By putting my prior over the matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$, instead of just a vector, I would have to use the matrix normal distribution which is considerably more complicated. The univariate derivation I added was not quite what you were referring to since it only uses a single value for $x$, not a vector. So I need to rewrite it where $y$ is a scalar and $x$ is a vector.

Comment: There was a typo in my comment, I did mean $\mathcal X\in\mathbb R^p$.

Comment: Even in the multivariate case, $\mathcal Y$ is a real rv.